# How to I give someone specific permissions on my Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

I have tried everything I have thought of to give myself and other people permissions. To make someone be able to warp or get a kit, I have to op them! Is there another way to give people specific permissions without giving them all the other permissions?

Comment: what's wrong with `/op player`?

Comment: @Ben I think it wants only certain permissions, not everything. Otherwise when you get warp, you can kick people

Comment: Exactly. i have world-edit, so they could destroy my whole world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the plug-in groupmanager (wiki link provided) [Group Manager](http://wiki.ess3.net/wiki/Group_Manager)
and install it for your server, the plug-in is to big to describe in one answer but the basic idea is there is different groups (newb, player, mod, admin and owner) each group has its different OPs such as /kit for newb and player
/kick for mod
/ban for admin and so on. Hope i helped!

Comment: That helped, but, I am talking about when i look at a plugin that i want to get and it says something like: 'Requires blank.blank.use to use this command'

Comment: Do i have to go into the config files and put it in somewhere?

Comment: i can't give someone access to /warp multiple homes /shop and lost more
how do i give the access to those commands?
plugins? what kind